# Passing const class object to std::function and std::bind lead compilation error

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, std-function, stdbind

When **const** **Serviceclass** used in **std::function** leads to compilation error.
If remove **const** the complication is successful.

**Code Flow** **:** Client::GetValue() is called which calls on **Server::datalist()**

**QUESTION :** Why can't i use **const** on **Serviceclass** ?

**SERVER SIDE**

```
     //                                      vvvvv (if const remove then compliation success.)
      typedef std::function<void(int, Status, const Serviceclass&)>
        Callback;
        //SECOND INVOKED
        void Server::datalist(int Id, sessionId,Callback callback) {
        std::unique_ptr<Serviceclass> ServiceObj = Serviceclass::create();
        callback(request_id, RESULT,*ServiceObj.get());
        }

       typedef std::vector<std::string> dataList;

       typedef std::function<void(int, Status, const dataList&)>callback_data;
       //FOURTH INVOKED
       void Server::getdata(int Id,callback_data){
        // callback called with datalist
       }
```

**CLIENT SIDE**

```
  //FIFTH INVOKE
 void Client::Foo(int Id,Status,const dataList& data){
    //impl
   }


 //THIRD INVOKED
void Client::Boo(int Id, 
                Status,
                const Serviceclass& Serviceclass){
  //            ^^^^^ (if const remove then compliation success.)
             Serviceclass.getdata(123,
                std::bind(&Client::Foo, this, std::placeholders::_1,
                          std::placeholders::_2, std::placeholders::_3));
}

//FIRST INVOKED
void Client::GetValue() {
        int Id = 123; 
        serverobj->datalist(
                        Id, sessionId,
                        std::bind(&Client::Boo, this, std::placeholders::_1,
                                std::placeholders::_2, std::placeholders::_3));
}
```

**ERROR**

```
In member function 'void Client::Boo(int, Status, const Serviceclass&)':
mycode.cc:68:76: error: passing 'const Serviceclass&' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
                               std::placeholders::_2, std::placeholders::_3));
```

Comment: Can you give us the exact error message?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I have added the compilation error. Please have a look.

Comment: The error seems to point inside `Client::Boo`, but you didn't include the function body. Which line it points to?

Comment: @josp the error message is not possible with the current implementatiojn

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I have update the code

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki

Comment: Looks like Serviceclass::getdata is not a const member function.

Comment: @Sopel Can you elaborate on it.

Comment: You can't call a non-const member function on a non-const object. Here you are trying to call non-const `Serviceclass::getdata` on `const Serviceclass&`. It has nothing to do with bind, std::function, or pretty much anything in the code provided.

Comment: @Sopel I didn't get your first statement ---> You can't call a non-const member function on a non-const object. ?  This is typo right?

Comment: Yea, i meant on const object, sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either make member function const or make non const object of Serviceclass.

```
//                                        ^^^^^ add const
void Server::getdata(int Id,callback_data)const {
        // callback called with datalist
       }
```